# When Mamp Pro expired, getting result fail in php

Tags: php, mamp, mamp-pro

I'am newbie in php and I'am working with it for getting results from api. Few days ago I connected the server and got result by using mamp pro free trial and I configure to debug it, it is worked, no problem in codes however now mamp pro is expired and I couldn't get the results. As far as I know, debugger not working without license but php should work in free version. Is there a problem I missed, can anyone help?

System info: MacOS 11.6

Comment: Just use a standard apache distribution and a common IDE for your development instead of that specific MacOS stuff.

Comment: @arkascha thank you! Sometimes i just overthing for the simple things. Now i removed mamp and i installed apache2. Now it is running nice.